# Why is translateY(-50%) needed to center an element which is at top: 50%?

Tags: html, css

I can see that this code works to align a div vertically within its parent element:

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

The question is why? My first thought was that the parent element encompassed more than the viewport. I made my parent viewport height equal `100vh` and width `100%`. That did not work. I still needed the translate or a negative margin offset. Why do I need a negative offset when the parent element is set to `margin: 0;`? Is it because of a computed margin that I'm not taking into account?

Comment: top is relative to the parent, transform is relative to itself. do the math, you'll how this results in centering the element

Answer (score 182, accepted):

#### top:0 **(default)**

By default, your element is at the top of the page, and the top of the element is at 0:

```
--------Top of Page--------
{element}


------Middle of  Page------



------Bottom of  Page------
```

#### top:50%

When you move it down by 50% height (50% of the entire page), the top of the element is at the 50% mark, meaning the element starts at 50% and is not centered.

```
--------Top of Page--------



------Middle of  Page------
{element}


------Bottom of  Page------
```

#### top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);

When the top of the element is at the halfway mark, we can move the element back up by half of its own height to center it with the whole page. That's exactly what `transform:translateY(-50%);` does:

```
--------Top of Page--------



{element}-Middle of Page---



------Bottom of  Page------
```

But why can't we just say `top: 25%` or something like that? I've made a quick snippet to show you the difference with that implementation:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: tomato;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #FFC4BA;
}
.inner.small {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
}
.inner.big {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
}
.percent {
  top: 25%
}
.transform {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<b>First row </b>looks alright, but that's because the gap works well with the 25%
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner percent"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner transform"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<b>Second row </b>made the center square a bit smaller, and the 25% now is too high as we'd expect the bottom of the element to reach 75%
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="small inner percent"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="small inner transform"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<b>Third row </b>now I've made the center box big and it ends lower than 75% making 25% start too late
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="big inner percent"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="big inner transform"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I partially understand what you are saying.  I have follow up questions which I added in the comments of @Quentin answer.

Comment: I like the visual representation of what's happening.  Thank you.

Comment: TL;DR `top` applies 50% from page/container height, `transform: translateY` applies -50% from own element height.

Answer (score 82):

While others have provided the answer that the -50 moves the inner element back up half it's own height, I thought this little animation showing the movement to `top: 50%;` first, followed by `transform: translateY(-50%);` second, might help.

```css
@keyframes centerMe {
  0% { top: 0%; transform: translateY(0%); }
  50% { top: 50%; transform: translateY(0%); }
  100% { top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); }
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px; width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  animation: centerMe 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* rules for example */
.hline,.vline{background:#000;position:absolute}.vline{height:100%;width:1px;left:calc(50% - .5px);top:0}.hline{width:100%;height:1px;top:calc(50% - .5px)}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="hline"></div>
  <div class="vline"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Shoot!  This is an awesome visual animation.  This is why I like front end more than back end programming.  Thank you.

Comment: @Itrainpr There's always a bounty! :-)

Answer (score 32):

> ```
> position: relative;
> top: 50%;
> ```

… moves the element down a distance equal to half the height of the parent.

Since the default position puts the *top* of the inner element at the *top* of the outer element, this puts the *top* of the inner element at the *middle* of the outer element.

> ```
> transform: translateY(-50%);
> ```

This moves the inner element back up a distance of half the height of the *inner* element.

Combining them puts the *middle* of the inner element at the *middle* of the parent element.

Comment: If I'm understanding what you are saying the top of the child element is being moved below the middle of the parent.  Then we are moving the child element back half the distance of the child element which equates to 25% of the parent element.  Is that correct?  If so, why not just move it down by doing `top: 25%`?  If not, then how does `top: 25%` differ from this work around?

Comment: "Then we are moving the child element back half the distance of the child element which equates to 25% of the parent element. Is that correct?" — It would be correct if (and only if) the child element had `height: 50%` (or equivalent), but nothing in the code in the question suggests that the height of the child is known.

Comment: @ltrainpr does that make sense do you understand why you can't just say 25% now?

Comment: @AndrewBone Yep, I get it now.  Thank you for taking the time to explain it.

Comment: Isn't the default positioning at the top of the outer element only when it's the first (space-taking) child, or when using `position: absolute` (assuming the outer element is positioned itself)?

Comment: @Bergi Sure, but this technique only really makes sense with `position: absolute` (and maybe `fixed`) anyways.

Answer (score 12):

> Why does top 50% need a -50% translate offset?

Rather than answering this question directly, I'm going to answer the more general question of:

**How does position anchoring work in CSS?**

Hopefully, in answering the question generally, you'll understand the parts that apply to your specific case.

---

### What do you mean by "position anchoring"?

Position anchoring is when a DOM node is positioned in a way that it is "anchored" to its parent in a given dimension. If the top left of the node is anchored to the top left of its parent, the nodes will stay aligned at their top left corner, no matter the size of either element.

### What does position anchoring look like?

I'm going to use a template for all further examples, so it's important to understand the base example.

```css
.container {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, darkred 0, darkred 50%, goldenrod 50%, goldenrod 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, darkgreen 0, darkgreen 50%, darkblue 50%, darkblue 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, darkred 0, darkred 50%, goldenrod 50%, goldenrod 100%), linear-gradient(to right, darkgreen 0, darkgreen 50%, darkblue 50%, darkblue 100%);
  background-position: top, bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 50.1%, 100% 50.1%;
  height: 70vh;
  margin: 15vh 15vw;
  position: relative;
  width: 70vw;
}
.box {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red 0, red 50%, yellow 50%, yellow 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, green 0, green 50%, blue 50%, blue 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 0, red 50%, yellow 50%, yellow 100%), linear-gradient(to right, green 0, green 50%, blue 50%, blue 100%);
  background-position: top, bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 50.1%, 100% 50.1%;
  height: 50vmin;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50vmin;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

This example shows a parent `.container` which has dark red, dark yellow, dark green, and dark blue quadrants to easily view alignment. Inside, it contains a `.box` which has red, yellow, green, and blue quadrants to show contrast for the alignment.

All further examples will have this boilerplate minified to make the relevant code stand out more.

Note that by default, the top left of the child is anchored to the top left of the parent.

### Parent Anchoring

Parent anchoring can be adjusted by using the `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` properties on the child element.

#### Top

Using the `top` property will anchor the top edge of the child to the top edge of the parent.

Assuming `bottom` isn't set, `top: 0` won't show differently than the default of `top: auto`

```css
.container{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),linear-gradient(to right,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:70vh;margin:15vh 15vw;position:relative;width:70vw;}.box{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:50vmin;position:absolute;width:50vmin;}

.box {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Using a percentage will align the top edge of the child at the given percentage from the top of the parent.

`top: 50%` is the middle of the parent:

```css
.container{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),linear-gradient(to right,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:70vh;margin:15vh 15vw;position:relative;width:70vw;}.box{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:50vmin;position:absolute;width:50vmin;}

.box {
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

`top: 100%` is the bottom of the parent:

```css
.container{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),linear-gradient(to right,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:70vh;margin:15vh 15vw;position:relative;width:70vw;}.box{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:50vmin;position:absolute;width:50vmin;}

.box {
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

#### Bottom Anchoring

Bottom anchoring will anchor the bottom edge of the child to the bottom edge of the parent:

```css
.container{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),linear-gradient(to right,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:70vh;margin:15vh 15vw;position:relative;width:70vw;}.box{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:50vmin;position:absolute;width:50vmin;}

.box {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

`bottom: 50%` is the middle of the parent, with the child aligned opposite from `top: 50%`:

```css
.container{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),linear-gradient(to right,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:70vh;margin:15vh 15vw;position:relative;width:70vw;}.box{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:50vmin;position:absolute;width:50vmin;}

.box {
  bottom: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

`bottom: 100%` is the top of the parent:

```css
.container{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),linear-gradient(to right,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:70vh;margin:15vh 15vw;position:relative;width:70vw;}.box{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:50vmin;position:absolute;width:50vmin;}

.box {
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

#### Left Anchoring

The `left` property will anchor the left edge of the child to the left edge of the parent.

Assuming `right` isn't set, `left: 0` won't show differently than the default of `left: auto`.

`left: 50%` is the middle of the parent:

```css
.container{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),linear-gradient(to right,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:70vh;margin:15vh 15vw;position:relative;width:70vw;}.box{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:50vmin;position:absolute;width:50vmin;}

.box {
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

`left: 100%` leaves the child hanging off the right side of the parent.

#### Right Anchoring

The `right` property will anchor the right edge of the child to the right edge of the parent:

`right: 50%` is the middle of the parent, with the child aligned opposite from `left: 50%`:

```css
.container{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),linear-gradient(to right,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:70vh;margin:15vh 15vw;position:relative;width:70vw;}.box{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:50vmin;position:absolute;width:50vmin;}

.box {
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

`right: 100%` leaves teh child hanging off the left side of the parent.

### Child Anchoring

Child anchoring can be adjusted independently from parent anchoring by making use of the `transform` property. Specifically the `translate`, `translateX`, and `translateY` functions will be used to bump the child box to use a different alignment.

The reason this works is because percentages in the `translate` value are relative to the *child*, while percentages in the `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` properties are relative to the *parent*.

#### Vertical Alignment

Using `transform: translateY()`, the alignment of the child can be bumped up or down.

`transform: translateY(0)` will leave the child where it is, and is generally not very useful.

When the child is anchored to the top of the parent, `transform: translateY(-50%)` will align the child at its center:

```css
.container{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),linear-gradient(to right,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:70vh;margin:15vh 15vw;position:relative;width:70vw;}.box{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:50vmin;position:absolute;width:50vmin;}

.box {
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Likewise, when the child is anchored to the bottom of the parent, `transform: translate(50%)` will align the child at its center:

```css
.container{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),linear-gradient(to right,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:70vh;margin:15vh 15vw;position:relative;width:70vw;}.box{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:50vmin;position:absolute;width:50vmin;}

.box {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

This also means that `top: 100%` is equivalent to `bottom: 0; transform: translateY(100%)`:

```css
.container{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),linear-gradient(to right,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:70vh;margin:15vh 15vw;position:relative;width:70vw;}.box{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:50vmin;position:absolute;width:50vmin;}

.box {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

#### Horizontal Alignment

Using `transform: translateX()`, the alignment of the child can be bumped left or right.

`transform: translateX(0)` will leave the child where it is by default.

When the child is anchored to the left of the parent, `transform: translateX(-50%)` will align the child at its center:

```css
.container{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),linear-gradient(to right,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:70vh;margin:15vh 15vw;position:relative;width:70vw;}.box{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:50vmin;position:absolute;width:50vmin;}

.box {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Likewise, when the child is anchored to the right of the parent, `transform: translateX(50%)` will align the child at its center:

```css
.container{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),linear-gradient(to right,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:70vh;margin:15vh 15vw;position:relative;width:70vw;}.box{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:50vmin;position:absolute;width:50vmin;}

.box {
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

`left: 100%` is equivalent to `right: 0; transform: translateX(100%)`.

### Center Anchoring

Centering is just a matter of aligning the child to the middle of the parent, and then bumping the child's origin into place.

```css
.container{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,darkred 0,darkred 50%,goldenrod 50%,goldenrod 100%),linear-gradient(to right,darkgreen 0,darkgreen 50%,darkblue 50%,darkblue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:70vh;margin:15vh 15vw;position:relative;width:70vw;}.box{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(left,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,red 0,red 50%,yellow 50%,yellow 100%),linear-gradient(to right,green 0,green 50%,blue 50%,blue 100%);background-position:top,bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 50.1%,100% 50.1%;height:50vmin;position:absolute;width:50vmin;}

.box {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Because of the symmetry, you could also use:

```
bottom: 50%;
right: 50%;
transform: translate(50%, 50%);
```

Comment: Great more general answer on positioning.  Maybe this would be a great way to beef up the CSS Positioning Documentation.  Check out editing http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/935/positioning#t=201611111730163945028

Comment: @zzzzBov If you take your content and invert it, presenting the most relevant content first and then expanding/explaining it gradually to the more general, it would be far more motivating, as every reader could stop early and still have a better understanding in context of the question.

Comment: @jpaugh, yes, there's quite a bit of improvement needed here still, not the least of which is to reduce the examples to be fewer, less repetitious, with better interactivity. Thank you for your feedback, and I'll see what I can do about incorporating it on my next draft.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I find that, as with code, writing prefers either the reader or the writer --- but not both. Cheers!