# Center vertical text on slider

Tags: css

I'm using a template for my [blog](http://www.harinapana.com) but I want to vertically align the text on the slider. I've tried changing the padding but then it's not centered while on mobile. Also when I change the top value from 0 to a percentile value it doesn't work.

```
.sora-slide .ty-thumb-bonos {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0!important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 560px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sora-slide .sora-slide-con {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 460px;
  display: table;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: So you want your text, button, etc centered vertically?

Comment: Could you post some markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this to `.sora-slide .sora-slide-con`

```
transform: translateY(-50%);
top: 50%;
```

and replace

```
margin: 15% auto;
```

with

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

This should do it, if I understand you.

Full css:

```
.sora-slide .sora-slide-con {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto; /* <- 0 auto */
  bottom: 0;
  top: 50%;       /* <- 50% instead of 0 */
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 460px;
  display: table;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* <- transformY -50% */
}
```

To understand why I added `transform` and `top`, see this anwser on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40530404/6773269 by
[Andrew Bone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4891666/andrew-bone).

He explained it very well.

Or like [aldo.roman.nurena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1121923/aldo-roman-nurena) said:

> TL;DR top applies 50% from page/container height, transform: translateY applies -50% from own element height.