# Align 3 images and 3 text lists horizontally w/ responsive

Tags: html, css

So I have a HTML/CSS problem I cannot seem to figure out. I am trying to align 3 images and text, all vertically in the following pattern: image text image text image text. I managed to do it on my own and it displays properly on my 13" MacBook. However, as soon as I shrink the window everything gets messed up. So, I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out a way to make the formatting respond to screen size?

P.S. I did get it to work for mobile though.

My code:

```css
.checklogostyle {
  vertical-align: middle; 
  margin-top: 10px; 
  padding-left:13%; 
  float:left;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .checklogostyle {
   vertical-align: middle; 
   margin-top: 30px; 
   margin-left:20px; 
    margin-right: 20px;
   float:left;
  }
}

.brandstext {
  padding-left:12%; 
  float:left; 
  text-align:left; 
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .brandstext {
   margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:20px;
   float:center; 
   text-align:left; 
  }
}


.brandstextlast {
  margin-left:20px; 
  float:left; 
  text-align:left; 
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .brandstextlast {
   margin-left:20px; 
    margin-top:20px;
   float:left; 
   text-align:left; 
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="checklogostyle">
      <img src="{{'checklogo.png' | asset_url}}">
  </div>
  <div class="brandstextlast">
    <span>Bernhardt <br> Century Furniture <br> John Richard <br> Hickory White</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checklogostyle">
      <img src="{{'checklogo.png' | asset_url}}">
  </div>
  <div class="brandstextlast">
    <span>Hooker Furniture <br> Hudson Valley <br> Robert Abbey <br> Theodore Alexander</span>
  </div>
   <div class="checklogostyle">
      <img src="{{'checklogo.png' | asset_url}}">
  </div>
  <div class="brandstextlast">
    <span>Visual Comfort <br> Vanguard Furniture <br> Uttermost <br> Yachtline</span>
  </div>
```

I am guessing that I need to wrap the content into come kind of container/wrapper, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Any help will be greatly appreciated, especially if someone explains the logic, so I can be able to do this in the future for other things!

Thanks!

[Image example of what I've achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07el6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `display: flex;` you could do easy responsive design. Use `flex-direction: row;` for large screens and `flex-direction: column;` for smaller ones.

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.flex-element {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.brandstextlast {
  margin-left:60px; 
}
.checklogostyle img {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.checklogostyle {
  position: relative;
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
  .flex-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .flex-element {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">
   <div class="flex-element">
      <div class="checklogostyle">
         <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
      </div>
      <div class="brandstextlast">
         <span>Bernhardt <br> Century Furniture <br> John Richard <br> Hickory White</span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="flex-element">
      <div class="checklogostyle">
         <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
      </div>
      <div class="brandstextlast">
         <span>Hooker Furniture <br> Hudson Valley <br> Robert Abbey <br> Theodore Alexander</span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="flex-element">
      <div class="checklogostyle">
         <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0327f4c2d7593ae3c7185a66d69d81b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
      </div>
      <div class="brandstextlast">
         <span>Visual Comfort <br> Vanguard Furniture <br> Uttermost <br> Yachtline</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! When I run your code here, it works. But when I put it into my webpage, my "check logo.png" images are not being displayed for some reason.. Any ideas?

Comment: So I was able to fix the image problem by removing .checklogo img { } code and putting some of it into the .checklogo class like this:

`.checklogostyle {
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}`

However, on mobile it now does [this (image)](https://imgur.com/a/1lhC2i8). Any way to center the logo with text make sure that the names don't cut into 2 lines?

Comment: Nevermind everything I said, I added a @media query for checklogo class and adjusted the top padding. Everything works now. Thanks! Leaving all this here so others in the future know how I fixed the issue.

Comment: if you could explain to me the logic behind top:50% and -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) and transform: translateY(-50%) I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Because 50% moves it down by half page, so you need to move it back up by half the height of the element itself. Great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530101/why-is-translatey-50-needed-to-center-an-element-which-is-at-top-50)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). I made few changes to your HTML as well.

Update: Check the full screen preview for desktop version, media query 680px is used which can be changed as per your requirement.

```css
.container-row {
  display: flex;
  max-width:1100px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  .container-row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.brandstext {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="checklogostyle">
      <img src="//placehold.it/60x60">
    </div>
    <div class="brandstext">
      <span>Bernhardt <br> Century Furniture <br> John Richard <br> Hickory White</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="checklogostyle">
      <img src="//placehold.it/60x60">
    </div>
    <div class="brandstext">
      <span>Hooker Furniture <br> Hudson Valley <br> Robert Abbey <br> Theodore Alexander</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="checklogostyle">
      <img src="//placehold.it/60x60">
    </div>
    <div class="brandstext">
      <span>Visual Comfort <br> Vanguard Furniture <br> Uttermost <br> Yachtline</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Your code works, but my images are being shrunk to approximately 30px30px for some reason. I tried assigning width:60px to my .checklogostyle but it had no effect. Any ideas?