# Why does positioning absolute elements to the left center the child?

Tags: css

This is nothing more than a request for someone to explain the logic behind these few CSS lines. I'm making a timeline for a website but am confused on why this code works.

I have a class `timeline_circle` that is `positioned absolute` to timeline_center. In the timeline_circle class, I move it `left:50;` and `transform: translateX(-50%);` which centers the timeline_circle. I can't wrap my head around why this works.

**Full code**

```
.timeline_center{
    background-color: var(--darkGrey);
    width: 0.5vw;

    border-radius: 1vh;
    justify-self: center;
    grid-area: timeline;

    position: relative;
}

.timeline_circle{
    width: 2vw;
    height: 2vw;

    border-radius: 1vw;
    background-color: var(--oceanBlue);

    position: absolute; 
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**Centered Circle in timeline**
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWGfd.png)

Comment: transform works on a size of element(width of the circle  in use case). So with transform -50% circle translate to -50%  to the left of it's width. 
And position 'absolute'  positioned based on parent relative element by default left 0%. you have defined 50% in ur case.

Comment: Check Andrew's answer, he explained exactly what's going on with the translate 50% https://stackoverflow.com/a/40530404/19060284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this is one of the tricks that is used for centering elements inside the parent, and the explanation is :

`position: absolute` will make that element move according to his first parent, in your case the `.timeline_center` is defined as parent by `position:relative`

when you use `left: 50%` that element moves from the left side of the parent for 50% of the parent's width, but remember that the TOP LEFT corner of the child moves for that amount.

So now, we have to make sure the center of the child is in middle, and not the TOP LEFT of it. We use `transform: translateX(-50%)` that makes the child move to the left direction for 50% of ITS width (child width) and now the center of the child is centered inside the parent